# R plot graph for data coordinates not showing up

Tags: r, plot

I have a set of data coordinates I'm trying to show on Rstudio.The issue starts when I try to run the plot function for a dataframe since that format does not show anything on the plot.

Here is the running code

```
{
alph=5
alphSeq1<-round(rand(1,alph),1)*10
alphSeq2<-round(rand(1,alph),1)*10
 
 alph_df<-data.frame(alphSeq1,alphSeq2)
 
 par(mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))

 #plot(alphSeq1, alphSeq2,cex = 1, pch = 3,type="p", xlab = "Var 1", ylab = "Var 2")
 
plot(alph_df$alphSeq1, alph_df$alphSeq2,type="p", xlab = "Var 1",  
ylab = "Var2",xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10))
}
```

Has anyone else run into this? I would really like to clarify on here in case.

Comment: I can't get the code to run, I get an error on the `rand(1, alpha)` function (`mosaic` v 1.8.3).

Comment: If this is the `rand()` function in the `mosaic` package, the second argument is the distribution function, not a number. Perhaps it is the `rand()` function in the `pracma `package? Your code should be complete including loading any packages that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

These modifications in your code will produce the plot. The problem was that the `rand()` function returns a one-row, five column matrix. When you combine them in `data.frame()` it creates a one-row, ten column matrix. Converting them to vectors creates a two column, five row data frame:

```
library(pracma)
{
alph=5
set.seed(42)
alphSeq1<-as.vector(round(rand(1,alph),1)*10)
alphSeq2<-as.vector(round(rand(1,alph),1)*10)

par(mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
plot(alph_df$alphSeq1, alph_df$alphSeq2,type="p", xlab = "Var 1",  
ylab = "Var2",xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10))
}
```

Comment: Yes the issue over my code is to make a for loop with a coordinate array & here I only have data. That's why the question still stands.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to make that clear and provide code that includes the loop.

Comment: I don't understand why dataframes don't work when arrays and vectors work here